# Why isn't my devise sending flash message "Signed out successfully."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My devise.en.yml has the sign_out message

```
sessions:
    signed_in: "Signed in successfully."
    signed_out: "Signed out successfully."
```

and I have a _messages.html.erb to check flash messages

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :class => "flash_#{name}" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and this is my signout button

```
<%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete' %>
```

All my other messages work correctly like signup, signin, etc, etc. The only one that doesnt work is my signout.

Why, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does it help if you use `:method => :delete` instead?

Comment: no :( that didn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for the people that was wondering what was wrong, my routing was messed up. after I sign out, the client was trying to access something it shouldn't therefore redirecting to another page while removing the "signed out successfully".